# Prove $\alpha \in\mathbb R$ is irrational, when $\cos(\alpha \pi) = \frac{1}{3}$

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers

I am trying to prove:

> If $\cos(\pi\alpha) = \frac{1}{3}$ then $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$

So far, I've tried making it into an exponential, since exponentials are easier to manipulate (at least for me), when compared to $\cos$ or $\sin$. So:

$$\cos(\pi\alpha)^2 + \sin(\pi\alpha)^2 = 1$$
$$\Big(\frac{1}{3}\Big)^2 + \sin(\pi\alpha)^2 = 1$$
$$\sin(\pi\alpha)^2 = \frac{8}{9}$$
$$\sin(\pi\alpha) = \frac{\sqrt{8}}{3}$$
$$\sin(\pi\alpha) = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$$

Then we can use Euler's formula:

$$e^{i\pi\alpha} = \cos(\pi\alpha) + i\sin(\pi\alpha) = \frac{1}{3} + i\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} = \frac{1+i2\sqrt{2}}{3}$$

Now take the log of both sides:

$$ \ln(e^{i\pi\alpha}) = \ln(\frac{1+i2\sqrt{2}}{3}) = \ln(1+i2\sqrt{2}) - \ln(3) = i\pi\alpha$$

$$\therefore \alpha = \frac{\ln(1+i2\sqrt{2}) - \ln(3)}{i\pi}$$

But, here I get stuck, and don't know how to show it is irrational, any ideas? (Even though it looks pretty darn irrational to me...) Should I be trying something else? I'm so lost...

Comment: Write $\alpha$ as $a+bi$ and use the angle sum formula for $\cos$. That should quickly let you establish that $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If it was rational, $e^{i\pi a}=\dfrac13+i\dfrac{2\sqrt2}3$ would have to be a root of unity (why?). However, I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: As for not being in $\mathbb{Q}$, there is [this theorem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2938).

Comment: @alex.jordan We want to show that it's _irrational_. We already know it's real.

Comment: @columbus8myhw OP asks to show it is in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. So I don't think OP already knows it is real, or else why not just ask to show it is not in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: How would you write this in math notation, then? `a in irrationals`

Comment: @columbus8myhw The most common thing would be $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @alex.jordan: Hahaha! I was taught that to say something is irrational you write $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. XD Didn't even consider doing it your way. Silly me. :)

Comment: I think $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ is correct for "$\alpha$ is an irrational number", which is after all a much stronger statement than merely "$\alpha$ is not a rational number" (since neither is, say, a brick).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just in case it is not assumed that $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, let $\alpha=a+bi$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Then 
$$\begin{align}
\cos(a\pi+b\pi i)&=\cos(a\pi)\sin(b\pi i)+\sin(a\pi)\cos(b\pi i)\\
\frac13&=i\cos(a\pi)\sinh(b\pi)+\sin(a\pi)\cosh(b\pi)\\
\end{align}$$
Since the left side is real, either $\cos(a\pi)$ or $\sinh(b\pi)$ is $0$. The former implies $\frac13=\pm\cosh(b\pi)$, which is impossible, So $\sinh(b\pi)=0$, which implies $b=0$, and so $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now assume that $\alpha$ is rational: $\alpha = \frac{a}{b}$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and consider

$$\left(e^{i\alpha\pi}\right)^b = e^{i\pi a} = (-1)^a$$

Now use that $e^{i\alpha\pi} = \frac{1}{3} \pm i\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$ to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Classical approach (looking what a fraction as solution would imply). Nice.

Comment: It's not clear that "the opposite" is that $\alpha$ is rational. OP seems to not be assuming that $\alpha$ is real, and needs that established too (which is easy enough).

Comment: @alex.jordan: Honestly, I thought it had to be real...

Comment: Hope you don't mind me editing your answer. Sorry if I overstepped---I won't be upset if you roll back.

Comment: @alex.jordan Fair enough. I took it for granted that $\alpha$ was real here. Yeah, no problem, saves me the work:)

Comment: @Winther: Oh! Oh! I think it get it! So is it since $(-1)^a$ where $a$ is an integer implies that the solution is either $-1$ or $1$, but since we can see that $(1/3 + i\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3})^b$ is not an integer then this implies that $\alpha$ is not an integer? Is my thinking correct?

Comment: @user667648 Yes, that is roughly the argument. To show it rigourously you can expand the term $(\ldots)^b$ using the binomial formula $(x+y)^n =\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}x^k y^{n-k}$ and write it as $A + iB$ and show that the real part $A$ cannot equal $(-1)^a$ and the imaginary part $B$ cannot equal $0$ at the same time.

Comment: @Winther: Thank you so much for your help! I will accept!

Comment: Very nice solution!

Answer (score 8):

Another possible approach. Assume, by contradiction, that $\alpha=\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}$. Consider the polynomial:
$$ g(x)=T_{2q}(x)-1 $$
where $T_{2q}(x)$ is a [Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). We have that $\frac{1}{3}$ is a rational root of $g(x)$, but this contradicts the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), since $g(0)=-2$ and the leading coefficient of $g(x)$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: Interesting! I have never heard of a Chebyshev polynomial! I will definitely look into this when I get further along in my mathematical career! :D

Comment: Heard about it but nice to see the application for this!

Answer (score 3):

A different approach is to use Dirichlet's well-known discontinuous function

$$
f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\lim_{j\to\infty}(\cos(k!\pi x))^{2j}\right),
$$

which is $1$ if $x$ is rational and $0$ if $x$ is irrational.

Since $\cos(\pi\alpha)=\frac{1}{3}$ implies $\alpha=\pm\frac{1}{\pi}\arccos\frac{1}{3}+2n$, with $n$ an arbitrary integer, we get

$$
f(\alpha)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\lim_{j\to\infty}[\cos(\pm k!\arccos(1/3))]^{2j}\right).
$$

Next, we use the fact that $\cos(nx)=T_{n}(\cos x)$, where $T_n$ denotes the $n$-th Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind. We see that
$$
\cos(\pm k!\arccos(1/3))]=T_{k!}(1/3)
$$

Using the recurrence relation $T_{n+1}(1/3)=\frac{2}{3}T_n(1/3)-T_{n-1}(1/3)$ (with $T_0(1/3)=1$ and $T_1(1/3)=1/3$), it is not difficult to prove that $|T_n(1/3)|<1$ for all $n\geq 1$. (I did it by solving the recurrence explicitly.) It is then trivial to show that both the outer and the inner limit equal $0$.